# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) File can't be opened for reading! in function 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read'

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I have been trying to run this (attendance system with face recognition).
I'm using python with opencv4.1.12 and after installing both opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python
i am still getting error . please can anyone tell me in detail what is wrong.

please can anyone tell me in detail what is wrong.

Comment: did you check that the path to the image you are trying to read is correct ? Also, are you on windows / linux / macos ?

Comment: We, of course, can't give you any details without seeing your code, but @Toyo has almost certainly nailed the problem.

Comment: _please can anyone tell me in detail what is wrong_ No, we can't, because you haven't shown us the details of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.